# Get double value from .Net TextBox in C++

Tags: .net, c++

How can I get the double value from a textbox in .NET using C++.  Do I have to get the text and do an atof() or is there an easier way?

Comment: When you say ".net" do you mean you're using C++/CLI, or do you mean you happen to be using Visual Studio.NET with C++?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you have to get the text and parse it - although you could stick within .NET and use [`Double.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx) instead of `atof()`, which lets you detect user error more easily.

`Convert.ToDouble` and `Double.Parse` would both throw exceptions in the case of failure; `atof()` will silently ignore bad input from what I remember. `Double.TryParse` just returns `true`/`false` to indicate success/failure, and uses an `out` parameter to pass back the result of the parse. This is usually the right thing to do for user input - you want to be able to detect the failure, but exceptions aren't really appropriate as users entering invalid data is a far from exceptional situation.

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse the text.

```
Double value = 0.0;

if (Double.TryParse(textBox.Text, out value))
{
    // Value is valid here.
}
else
{
   // Handle invalid input here.
}
```

Comment: If you're going to throw a FormatException on failure you might as well just use Double.Parse() :)  (You should also be passing in "value" as an out parameter, which means you don't need to initialize it to start with.)

Comment: I just typed to quick and forgott out value - there is no single parameter overload at all. The exception was just meant as example, but you are right, a bad example. And I prefer to explictly initialize variables.

Comment: If you explicitly initialize a variable when that value can never be used, surely that's misleading isn't it? When it's immediately used as an out parameter, whatever value you put in is guaranteed to be overwritten unless an exception is thrown. Why pretend that the previous value was important?

Comment: I don't know if this is the case in the CLR/C#, but there are good reasons to always initialize FP values http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/07/02/8679191.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In .NET you can use [Double.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.parse.aspx), [Double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx), or [Convert.ToDouble](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todouble.aspx).